# SetSystemTimeAdjustment Function - Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I am working on an application that uses the SetSystemTimeAdjustment function. However, I am getting a permissions error when that function is called - error code 1314.

I have updated my "User Rights" in Windows for operating as OS and setting system time to include administrators, users, but I still get the error.

Here's a sample of the code (not actual, but similar to): http://winterdom.com/dev/security/tokens

Comment: If you're using Vista or Win7, can you try running it as an administrator? Just right click on it and click "Run as Administrator." Alternatively try turning UAC off. I realise you've changed the user rights, but it's still best to try as an admin first.

Answer (score 4):

The error code 1314 shows clear, that you don't enable the privilege `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` required for successful working of the function [SetSystemTimeAdjustment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724943%28VS.85%29.aspx). An example how to enable privilege you can find for example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619%28VS.85%29.aspx).

One more advice. If you start as administrator [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) you can verify which privileges has every process (you need `SeSystemtimePrivilege`), and which from the privileges are currently enabled or disabled.

To be sure that you will never have UAC problem, you should include in your program as a resource the [UAC Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) having

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

or

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

Depend on the version of the Visual Studio which you use it could be just of the project setting ("Linker" / "Manifest file", "UAC Execution Level")